# importing configuration from subfolders

Tags: python, django, configuration

I am trying to tidy up my configuration file, and I wanted to split it into several files that can be edited based on the deployment need.

So in my project directy I have a subdirectory called config containing a few specific configuration files

My "main" configuration file (settings.py) is located in my project directory (where models.py and manage.py are). Sub-configuration files are in the "config" directory:

```
ProjectName
  + config
      - common.py
      - specific.py
  - settings.py
```

This is what the settings.py file looks like:

```
appPath = "path/to/my/app"
configPath = "path/to/my/app/config"

folders = [os.path.dirname(appPath), os.path.dirname(configPath)]

for f in folders:
  if f not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, f)

from MyApp.config import common
from MyApp.config import specific
```

However, this does not seem to set any of the settings I am using in the common.py and specific.py files.

I also tried the following:

```
from MyApp.config import common as django_settings
```

and

```
from MyApp.config.common import *
```

None of these seem to work.

I have the `__init__.py` in my config directory

Thanks,

Comment: Where are these imports being done - ie what is your "config" file?

Comment: @Daniel: added explanation above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do

```
from config.common import *
from config.specific import *
```

You shouldn't have to mess with the Python path, either, as Django's `manage.py` script will add the its directory and its parent to the path.